Covering space being implied by finiteness of pre-image
I'm struggling to finish a proof about coverings. The question is as follow:
Let $ p: E \to B $ be a local homeomorphism. Show that, if $ |p^{-1}(b)| = |p^{-1}(b')| < \infty $ for all $ b, b' \in B $, then $ p $ is a covering.
My attempt to a solution is:
Let $b \in p(E)$. For each $x \in p^{-1}(b)$. Since $p$ is a local homeo, there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $p|{U_x}$ is a homeo onto its image. As $p$ is a local homeo, $W_x = p(U_x)$ is an open neighborhood of $b$. Now consider $W = \bigcap_{x\in p^{-1}(b)} W_x$. Being the finite intersection of open sets, $W$ is open.
Now consider $V_x = p^{-1}[W] \cap U_x$.
Thus, we will have that $p^{-1}[W] = \bigcup_{x \in p^{-1}(b)} V_x$ and $p|_{V_x}$ are homeomorphisms onto $W$.
The argument concludes because, since $|p^{-1}(b)|$ is independent of $b$, then $p$ is surjective and, therefore, we can indeed choose $b \in B$.
There is a mistake, however, because I couldn't guarantee that $V_x \cap V_y = \emptyset$ whenever $x\neq y$. Any hint is appreciated.

Did you forget to assume Hausdorff?

No, the space is not supposed to be Hausdorff. The question is as posed, but I could not find a counter example nevertheless.

Hint: Since there is no Hausdorff assumption, there is a counter-example with $E$ of the cardinality $4$. I will leave you the rest: There are not that many topological spaces of cardinalities $4$ and $2$ and local homeomorphisms between these.
If you add the Hausdorff assumption, this question becomes a duplicate...
